# Need Help to create a Fancy 'Key-Idea' Box for Article

Tags: formatting, boxes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Highlight Boxes in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66820/how-to-create-highlight-boxes-in-latex)

I am writing an Article. I am trying to create a 'Key-Idea Box' like the one shown below:

[image]

Can somebody help me creating a similar box as the one shown above?

Thanks.