# Draw an eye with an arc with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pspicture

I want to draw something like this : an eye with an arc.

I started like this but I don't know how to continue

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc(0:-180:3);
\draw[very thick,yshift=6cm](-3,0) .. controls (-2,2) and (2,2) .. (3,0) .. controls (2,-2) and (-2,-2) .. (-3,0)--cycle;                                                                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Once again (since you already posted this question before), it could be helpful to know exactly what this drawing means and what exact part of it you're struggling with. In particular, is this meant to be a 3D drawing? And if yes, on what plane are the different parts meant to be drawn?

Comment: No not 3d it is an eue with an arc that's all

Comment: This seems related to this topic : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94082/help-with-the-design-of-an-eye-in-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so here we go. Since I don't really know what you need, I'll give it a try.

[image: an eye with an arc]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[scale=2]}]
        \def\xr{5}
        \draw[fill=pink] (\xr,0) to [out=120,in=60] (-\xr,0) to [out=-60,in=-120] (\xr,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (\xr,0) to [out=down,in=down,looseness=3] (-\xr,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2*\xr,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5*\xr);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (-1.5*\xr,-1.5*\xr);
        
        \foreach \angle in {30,60,120,150,...,330}
            {
            \ifnum\angle=270
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\coef}{sqrt(abs(cos(60)))}%
            \else
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\coef}{sqrt(abs(cos(\angle)))}%
            \fi
            \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (\angle:1.1*\xr*\coef);
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it very nice thank you very much  . Please how I can learn this ?

Comment: You can read the [PGF-Ti*k*Z manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Or you can look for simplified tutorials on the Internet, to begin with.