# Flexible brackets around text

Tags: brackets

Is there any way to make flexible brackets around some text?

So I tried to use `fancyvrb` and got something like this:

[image: Brackets with fancyvrb]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
    {MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
    {gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all,
     frame=single,framerule=3pt,framesep=5mm,rulecolor=\color{darkblue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{MyVerbatim}
some text some text some 
some text some text some 
some text some text some 
\end{MyVerbatim}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\end{document}
```

However, I am unhapy with it, because of the misuse of `fancvrb`.

I want to be able to define the thickness of the rule, the
size of the corners or the spaces. A good candidate would be
a package similar to `dashedbox`.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a job for the `mdframed` package.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create Highlight Boxes in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66820/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the user's comment, I EDITED the answer for ease of use:

This solution just uses an `\fbox` whose separation and rule thickness are set with `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.  It then uses a stack to place the verbatimbox content into a white box, vertically augmented to overwrite some of the `\fbox` border in order to give the appearance of brackets.

To simplify things, I have created the `\bracetext` macro which takes four arguments.  The first is the stuff to embrace.  It can be a verbbox, plain text, a parbox, whatever.  The second argument is the rule thickness of the brace (`\fboxrule`).  The third argument is the gap around the object (`\fboxsep`).  The last argument is the horizontal width of the brace prong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\bracetext[4]{%
\fboxrule=#2
\fboxsep=#3
\def\hsep{#4}
\stackon[-\fboxrule-.1pt]{%
\textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\hspace{\hsep}#1\hspace{\hsep}}}%
}{\colorbox{white}{\addvbuffer[\the\fboxrule+.1pt]{#1}}}
}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}
This is
a \verbatim
test
\end{verbbox}
\bracetext{\theverbbox}{1pt}{3pt}{5pt}

\bracetext{This is a test}{2pt}{4pt}{5pt}

\bracetext{\parbox{1in}{This is text in a 1 inch parbox}}{4pt}{5pt}{3pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am starting to implement your package in some of my documents but when I read your documentation, you don't have a lot of examples. It would be nice to provide some standard and advanced examples.

Comment: @azetina  Do you mean `verbatimbox` or `stackengine`?  I think the latter package documentation give a fair number of examples.  But by all means, feel free to follow up with any questions.

Comment: Its the `stackengine`. I have been only able to do two answers here on TeX.SX because I cannot seem to find examples to study from and see where it can be implemented. I think its just the way you prepared your documentation. But I will get it eventually by following how you answer questions.

Comment: @azetina I will certainly give some thought on including more examples in the docs.  In the meantime, I have answered a large number of questions on this site, using `stackengine`.  And so a search for the package name will yield quite an assortment from which to choose.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers guy's. Many of the examples use '[]' so, they are not flexible enough.

@StevenB.Segletes: I will try this, but it's really not easy, so I need to dive into stackengine.

Comment: @britzelfix  Please see my revised answer.  I have tried to automate the process to make it easier.