# How to enclosure a text block into big square brackets?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, text-decorations

everybody.  I need to enclosure a text block into big square brackets.  Something like this (I need to replicate it, more or less):
[image]

I've read that it could be possible with tikz but I don't know anything about that package.  Even, I found a code that reproduce something similar but with braces in this post:
[Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text)
The code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newtcolorbox{rightbrace}{%
    enhanced jigsaw, 
    breakable, % allow page breaks
    frame hidden, % hide the default frame
    overlay={%
        \draw [
            fill=none, % fill paper
            decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},
            decorate,
            ultra thick,
            gray,
        ]
        % right line
        (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);
    },
    % paragraph skips obeyed within tcolorbox
    parbox=false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item First line
          \begin{rightbrace}
            \item Second line 
            \item Third line, which is quite long and seemingly tedious in the extreme
            \item Fourth line, which isn't as long as the third 
          \end{rightbrace}
    \item Fifth line
\end{itemize}

\begin{rightbrace}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{rightbrace}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

How could I put the square brackets around a block of text? (Using tikz, tcolobox or whatever package then can be useful for it).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related/duplicate?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66820/how-to-create-highlight-boxes-in-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148254/flexible-brackets-around-text, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158649/deep-brackets-around-a-text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I adapted the code to match your picture.

This is the output:

[image]

And the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{squarebrackets}[2][]{%
  empty,
  breakable,
  boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,left=5mm,right=5mm,
  toptitle=3mm,bottomtitle=1mm,
  title=\colorbox{yellow}{#2},
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  underlay={%
    \draw[gray!50,line width=1mm]
      ([xshift=5mm,yshift=-0.5mm]frame.north west)--
      ([xshift=0.5mm,yshift=-0.5mm]frame.north west)--
      ([xshift=0.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]frame.south west)--
      ([xshift=5mm,yshift=0.5mm]frame.south west)
      ([xshift=-5mm,yshift=-0.5mm]frame.north east)--
      ([xshift=-0.5mm,yshift=-0.5mm]frame.north east)--
      ([xshift=-0.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]frame.south east)--
      ([xshift=-5mm,yshift=0.5mm]frame.south east)
      ;
  },
  % paragraph skips obeyed within tcolorbox
  parbox=false,#1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{squarebrackets}{Corolario}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{squarebrackets}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  Your code worked!!  Now, I have a new problem: in several "Corolarios" I have to insert an image between two paragraph and, when I make the corolario in the squarebrackets environment, the figure environment doesn't work. So, I had to put the images ( \includegraphics) in a minipage environment.  So, I lost the possibility to use \caption for automatically numbering.  How could I to modify this code in order to the possiblity to use the figure environment?

Comment: @Fabio For non-floating environments, you can use `\captionof` from the `caption` package, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45073/adding-a-caption-to-a-non-float-environment