# Attempting to Format Symbol and Text in Two Columns

Tags: two-column, typography, fontawesome

I use markdown to take school notes. They are later converted, via Pandoc to HTML and PDF (through LaTeX templates). I am trying to typeset a Symbol (floated left) to multiple lines of text. In the browser it looks like this:

[image: Example 1 of two column typesetting]
or
[image: Example 2 of two column typesetting]

This works in HTML by inserting the raw HTML and CSS (using floats and padding or tables). Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in the LaTeX?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! E.g. `tcolorbox` allows you to do such things, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66822/121799 .